# How can Auto Select React Material TextField's Value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

***This a react state:***

```
const [filterByInvoiceNo, setFilterByInvoiceNo] = useState( 0 );
```

***This is React Material TextField:***

```
        <TextField
            size="small"
            type="number"
            label="Invoice No"
            variant="outlined"
            value={filterByInvoiceNo}
            onChange={e => {
              setFilterByInvoiceNo( e.target.value );
            }}
          />
```

I need to auto select totally field value when I click TextField Box.

***Please see the image***

[image]

Comment: use inputRef={input => input && input.focus()} if it's react Material UI TextField.

Comment: refer React Material UI Docs - https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work

```js
<TextField
    size="small"
    type="number"
    label="Invoice No"
    variant="outlined"
    value={filterByInvoiceNo}
    onChange={e => {
    setFilterByInvoiceNo( e.target.value );
    }}
    onFocus={e => {e.target.select();}}
/>
```